# one column value to display another column with if condition using DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Need to display column base on another column value like below

```
data: 'username',
render: function (data, type) {
  if ({data:"status"} === 'N') {
    return `<a href="#"> ${data}</a>`;
  } else {
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  }
}
```

Need display link while status is N but every time it is showing without link.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `{data:"status"} === 'N'`? Why would that evaluate to `true`?

Comment: It's not clear from your question (you have not shown us sufficient code, or any of your data) but maybe you need to use `"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) { ... }`. Then you can use the `row` variable to access any value, from any column, in the row. Use `console.log( row )` to see what is in `row`.

Comment: if ({data. status } === 'N') {
    return `<a href="#"> ${data}</a>`;
  } else {
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  }  Above code is original one  I try to once column value check with display another column  @andrewJames

Comment: @andrewJames, Thank you for  focusing on my query and I got the solution for that like below render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        return data.firstName +' '+ data.lastName;
    } I think if we get the all row detail to particular condition you need to add row as a parameter then you get the current row of value in it. so you can compare of any condition check with it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, I got your suggestion and it is working fine thank you.